# Inverting buffer - simple circuit, weird problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, buffer

i want to make a unity gain inverting buffer. It's usually done by placing 2 equal resistors - in this case R1 = R2 = 47k. I wanted to simulate it in LTSpice and something is definitely wrong. Is this simple circuit designed bad?

thanks

[image: invertingbuffer]

Comment: Next time read the App Notes. This is like spoon feeding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LT1115 is not intended for unity gain (+ or - gains) and will oscillate when used this way. Luckily the sim model responded as the real device does. Read the following extract from the data sheet on page 7 under applications information: -

> The LT1115 is a very high performance op amp, but not necessarily one
>   which is optimized for universal application. Because of very low
>   voltage noise and the resulting high gain-bandwidth product, the
>   device is most applicable to relatively high gain applications. Thus,
>   while the LT1115 will provide notably superior performance to the 5534
>   in most applications, the device may require circuit modifications to
>   be used at very low noise gains. The part is not generally applicable
>   for unity gain followers or inverters.

Note also the phase margin falling to zero (oscillatory condition) before open-loop gain drops to unity: -

[image]